# Proof that the maximum of $F(x)=\arctan(aTx)-\arctan(Tx)$ is $\arcsin(\frac{a-1}{a+1})$

Tags: trigonometry

$a$ and $T$ are constants.
I have plotted $F(x)$ and $y=\arcsin(\frac{a-1}{a+1})$ for different values of $a$ and found that it's true.
I tried using $\arctan(x)=\arcsin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x²}})$.
I also tried calculating the derivative of $F(x)$ but I couldn't get to extract an $\arcsin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equating $F'(x)$ to zero,

$\begin{align}\frac{aT}{1+(aTx)^2}= \frac{T}{1+(Tx)^2} &\Rightarrow a+a(Tx)^2 = 1+ (aTx)^2 \\&\Rightarrow (a-1) = aT^2x^2(a-1) \\&\Rightarrow \boxed{x = \pm\frac{1}{T\sqrt a}}\end{align}$

> $T$ can't be zero and $a$ can't be $1$, as these would make the function $F(x) = 0$.

Using these values of $x$, check if $F''(x)<0$ for maxima to occur.

For $x=  \frac{1}{T\sqrt a}$

$\begin{align}F(\frac{1}{T\sqrt a}) &= \arctan(\sqrt a) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\right) \\\\&= \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt a - \frac{1}{\sqrt a}}{1+1}\right) \\\\& = \arctan\left(\frac{a-1}{2
\sqrt a}\right) \\\\&= \arcsin\left(\frac{(a-1)/(2\sqrt a)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{(a-1)^2}{4a}}}\right) \\\\&= \arcsin \left(\frac{a-1}{a+1}\right)\end{align}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think you meant "check F''<0 for maxima to occur".

Comment: Yeah, thanks for correcting

Answer (score 2):

Computing the derivative
$$F'(x)=\frac{a T}{a^2 T^2 x^2+1}-\frac{T}{T^2 x^2+1}$$ and we want it to be equal to $0$. This happens at
$$x_*=\pm \frac{1}{T \sqrt{a}}$$

Now, we need to check the second derivative
$$F''\left(\pm\frac{1}{T\sqrt{a} }\right)=\mp\frac{2 (a-1) a^{3/2} T^2}{(a+1)^2}$$ So, if $a>1$ the maximum is at $x_*=\frac{1}{T\sqrt{a}}$ and vice-versa.
$$F\left(+\frac{1}{T\sqrt{a} }\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a-1}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)$$
$$F\left(-\frac{1}{T\sqrt{a} }\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1-a}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)$$ and your result is true if you take the positive solution.

Now, play with a few trigonometric relations.

Comment: Thank you Claude!